# setting preferredContentSize does not trigger preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:

Tags: ios, ios8

View controller X presents a view controller Y.

```
Y.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet
[X presentViewController:Y...]
```

While being presented, Y presents another view controller, Z.

```
Z.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext
[Y presentViewController:Z...]
```

After being presented, Z sets its preferredContentSize to a different size. Shouldn't  preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer: be called on Y or X? It's not and I wonder why.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `UINavigationController` in there somewhere? It seems to be blocking those messages for me.

Comment: Find anything since then ?